# Survival analysis

Tags: r, numeric

I get the following error when I run the code below

```
Error in as.numeric(time) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Code:

```
mod <- survreg((Surv(as.numeric(time), event=status)) ~ prison+dose+clinic,
                data = meth, 
                dist = "lognormal")
```

Hope someone can help with this.

Sandeep

Comment: meth is the name of my data set. thanks

Comment: If I code the query as 'mod <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ prison + dose + clinic, data=meth, dist="lognormal")' then I get an error saying that 'Error in Surv(time, status) : Time variable is not numeric'

Comment: Sorry mate, just realized what you ment  ' "ID"     "Clinic" "Status" "Time"   "Prison" "Dose"

Comment: #1 Will you accept answers from past questions? #2 You should by now have got the idea to provide a minimal reproducible example to R problems. You code returns `Error in terms.formula(formula, special, data = data): object 'meth' not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
mod <- survreg((Surv(as.numeric(Time), event=Status)) ~ Prison+Dose+Clinic,
            data = meth, 
            dist = "lognormal")
```

as you reported to me that:

```
names(meth)
# [1] "ID" "Clinic" "Status" "Time" "Prison" "Dose"
```

Note, it is `Time`, not `time`; Also, it is `Status`, not `status`. In fact, all variables names start with a capital letter!

Comment: Thanks mate, but it threw up this error   'Error in Surv(as.numeric(Time), event = status) : Time and status are different lengths'

Comment: lengths(meth)  ID Clinic Status   Time Prison   Dose 
   238    238    238    238    238    238

Comment: > class(meth)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: All working now mate. Made school boy error with Name formats when typing

Comment: Will do mate, I didnt know you have to accept answers. Let me know if I havent accepted your anser I clicked in the grey tick mark